# Regex to find and display count of every word in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string and array. I want to find occurence of each element of array in the string.

```
my $str = 'acacabcatghhellomvnsdb';
my $words = ["aca","cat","hello","world"];
```

In above case, result should be: `"aca" : 2 , "cat" : 1 , "hello" : 1 , "world" : 0`, our focus in output shpuld be in count, not on formatting. 
 I have tried resetting string index using `pos` as well, but I'm not getting right output. Below is my program:

```
my $str = 'acacabcatghhellomvnsdb';
my $words = ["aca","cat","hello","world"];

my $cnt = {};
for my $word (@$words) {
    $cnt->{$word} ++  while ($str =~ /$word/g);
    my $c = () = $str =~ /$word/
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $cnt;
```

Output is: `'cat' => 1, 'hello' => 1, 'aca' => 1`, However `aca` should be `2`.

Comment: So you want to find the overlapping ones, like _**aca**cab..._ and _ac**aca**b..._?

Comment: Since one character can be in two matches, you should use positive lookahead to take only the initial position where the word occur, like `/(?=word)/` instead of `/word/`